# C++ "deque iterator not dereferencable" exception is thrown in debug mode

Tags: c++, iterator, deque

I am getting an exception thrown error of "deque iterator not dereferencable" while running my code in debug mode. The code is below -

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    queue<int> myqueue;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        myqueue.push(i);
        myqueue.front();

        cout << "myqueue.front() is = " << myqueue.front() << endl;

        myqueue.pop();
    }

    cout << "myqueue.front() is now = " << myqueue.front() << endl;   /// Getting error here

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

when I put a check for the size of queue before accessing myqueue.front(), then it is not getting crash as code modified below -

```cpp
if (myqueue.size() > 0)
    cout << "myqueue.front() is now = " << myqueue.front() << endl;
```

The code is perfectly working fine in Release mode without the (myqueue.size() > 0) check, however it is getting crash at run time in Debug mode only.

Can anyone help me to let me know why it is getting crash in debug mode only. and how to get rid of the error in debug mode.

Comment: isn't the queue empty at the end? Meaning there is no front so you can't do `cout << "myqueue.front() is now = " << myqueue.front() << endl;` in debug mode of Visual Studio it checks some of these bad things that you are doing and complains.

Comment: ***The code is perfectly working fine in Release mode*** In release mode the compiler is doing no check at all so you have undefined behavior which unfortunately sometimes appears to work

Comment: The error is actually in the code and debug mode is what is helping you by causing a crash instead of letting your program run with undefined behavior. Your for loop adds an int to your queue with `push`, gets the front of the queue with `front`, and then removes the first and only item in your queue with `pop`. At this point your queue is empty. After your loop you then decide to output `myqueue.front()` which does not exist since there are no elements in your queue. This produces undefined behavior in your program.

Answer (score 1):

You are touching an **Undefined Behavior** here because you are accessing the front element even though your `std::queue<int>` is empty. That's why the following statement:

```cpp
std::cout << "myqueue.front() is now = " << myqueue.front() << std::endl;
```

may sometimes give you the random value (one of the values your `std::queue<int>` contained before) or cause a crash (which is happening in your case) - Undefined Behavior.

That's why it is always a good idea to check if the `std::queue` has any elements before trying to access them:

```cpp
if (!myqueue.empty()) {
    std::cout << "myqueue.front() is now = " << myqueue.front() << std::endl;
}
```